# python | making a file and incrementing the name every run

Tags: python, file, logging, filenames

ok so, i have a program that runs and every time it executes a code it writes a comment to a log file:

```
def logger(event):
event = str(event)
current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
current_time_for_log = current_date.strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S --- ')
date_file_name = current_date.strftime('%d-%m-%y')
with open('{}'.format(date_file_name), 'a+') as log_file:
    log_file.write('-' * 50 + '\n' + '\n')
    log_file.write(current_time_for_log + event + '\n')
```

if the file exist it will write to the file if it does not it creates the file and names it the current date(i.e 13-09-18)

now what i want to accomplish and just cant figure out how to do using os.path.exist() is that every time i run the program is will check if there is a file with current date if not create it and if it does exist create a file with the same date but add '_1' to it:

first time running the program-
creates the file 13-09-18

second time """-
creates the file 13-09-18_1

third time """-
creates the file 13-09-18_2

etc...

what happens when i use the os.path.exist() is at best i get an incrementing file names but it does that everytime the function is called so every comment gets a file with incrementing names instead of writing all the comments of the run to the same file..

Comment: Please post your best coding attempt.  Stack Overflow is much more effective at fixing incorrect code than providing new code from scratch.

Comment: Just put the file creation code outside the logger function

Comment: i deleted it and now i cant really replicate it again... anyway i'll try to replicate it..

Comment: def logger(event):
    event = str(event)
    current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_time_for_log = current_date.strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S --- ')
    date_file_name = current_date.strftime('%d-%m-%y')
    i = 0
    while os.path.exists(date_file_name):
        i +=1
    with open('{}{}{}'.format(date_file_name, '_', str(i)), 'a+') as log_file:
        log_file.write('-' * 50 + '\n' + '\n')
        log_file.write(current_time_for_log + event + '\n')
is the best i can do.. it just writes a new file names 13-09-18_0 and acts the same as a the normal code i posted..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a second function and will have to call it outside your `logger` function. Something like this:

```
def getlogfile(prefix):
    file_list = [filename for filename in os.listdir('.') if filename.startswith(prefix)]
    if prefix not in file_list:
        # file doesn't exist yet; make it.
        target_name = prefix
    else:
        # get latest one
        number_list = [int(filename[-1]) for filename in file_list if filename[-2] == '_']
        try:
            latest_num = sorted(number_list)[-1]
            target_name = '{}_{}'.format(prefix, latest_num + 1)
        except IndexError:
            # there aren't any underscored names yet
            target_name = '{}_1'.format(prefix)
    return target_name


def logger(event, date_file_name):
    event = str(event)
    current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_time_for_log = current_date.strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S --- ')    
    with open('{}'.format(date_file_name), 'a+') as log_file:
        log_file.write('-' * 50 + '\n' + '\n')
        log_file.write(current_time_for_log + event + '\n')

date_file_name = getlogfile(datetime.date.today().strftime('%d-%m-%y'))

logger('first call, new file', date_file_name)
logger('second call, same file', date_file_name)
```

should do the trick for you.

Comment: works great but only when i delete the logger argument date_file_name, why?

Comment: if i dont delete it it returns an error TypeError: logger() missing 1 required positional argument: 'date_file_name'

Comment: I didn't include an example of it being called. It should be called with two arguments, the second one being the prefix name. I'll edit my answer to include some sample calls.

Comment: does it have to run this way? i mean right now when i log some thing for example
'/code' 
def number(log):
    x = 1
    log('x is 1')

number(logger) 'code'

Comment: You can always reduce the code quality a bit and make the `date_file_name` a global. That's pretty much what you already did when you removed the second argument and called it with one. You could also encapsulate the logger in a class and make the filename a data attribute.